# $_POST not showing results

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm using the simple following code to create a form and receive its values in another page:

firstpage.php

```
<form action="checklogin.php" method="post" >
<table border=1>
<tr><td>Username </td><td><input type="text" name="txtuser" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password </td><td><input type="text" name="txtpwd" /></br>
</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Login now"  name="btnsub"/>
</table> 
</form>
```

checklogin.php

```
<html>
<body>
Welcome <?php echo $_POST['txtuser']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This code does not show the value of the input `txtuser` in the nxtpage.php in all browsers.

Comment: You're posting to `checklogin.php` but are trying to `echo` the contents on `nextpage.php`. I'd call that a problem.

Comment: Please accept more of your previous answers. In this instance you're not posting data to nextpage.php but checklogin.php so the $_POST variable is empty.

Comment: Please always use `htmlspecialchars` if you want to output user input to an HTML page.

Comment: I'm redirecting to checklogin.php only using the action attribute of form .Plz ignore the nextlogin.php..Now plz figure out the reason y is it not showing txtuser content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your form target checklogin.php or nxtpage.php? Since if it is checklogin.php, quite naturally nxtpage.php will not receive the POST variables sent to checklogin.php.

Unless you're just doing something very simple, you want to use sessions - for example, see [this tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) about sessions.

Answer (score 3):

You're POSTing to `checklogin.php`. Of *course* `nextpage.php` won't have the POST value. Try sticking it in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [passing variable to another page](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/12009-passing-variables-from-one-page-to-another/).